# Calculating the volume under the surface $z = x^2 + y^2$ and above $D$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, volume, multiple-integral

Given:

$$D = \left\{(x,y) | 1 \leq x^2 +y^2 \leq 100, ~~ \frac{x \sqrt{3}}{3} \leq y \leq x \sqrt{3} \right\}$$

Calculate the Volume under the surface $$z = x^2 + y^2$$

And above $D$.

My try:

$$I = \iint_D x^2 + y^2 \,dx\,dy$$

We can write $D$ as:

$$D = \left\{(x,y) | 1 \leq x^2 +y^2 \leq 100, ~~ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \leq \frac{y}{x} \leq  \sqrt{3} \right\}$$

And change to $u,v$ as the following:

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
 u = x^2 + y^2 \\ v = \frac{y}{x}
\end{matrix}\right.$$

So the set $D$ would be:
$$D = \left\{(u,v) | 1 \leq u \leq 100, ~~ \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \leq v \leq  \sqrt{3} \right\}$$

Now, because we changed the variables, we need to calculate the Jacobian:

$$ J = \frac{ D(x,y)}{D(u,v)} = \frac{1}{\frac{D(u,v)}{D(x,y)}} = \frac{1}{\begin{vmatrix}
u_x & u_y\\ 
v_x & v_y
\end{vmatrix}} = \frac{1}{\begin{vmatrix}
2x & 2y\\ 
-\frac{y}{x^2} & \frac1x
\end{vmatrix}} = \frac{1}{2+ 2 (\frac{y}{x})^2}$$

$$J = \frac{1}{2(1+v^2)}$$

And we can calculate the integral as so:

$$\iint_{D_{uv}} u \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{1+v^2} \,du\,dv = \frac{1}{2} \int_1^{100} ( \int_{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}^{\sqrt{3}} \frac{u}{1+v^2} du)dv = \frac{1}{2} \int_1^{100} \frac{1}{1+v^2} ( \frac{ (\sqrt{3})^2 - (\frac{1}{ \sqrt{3}})^2}{2})dv = \frac23 \int_1^{100} \frac{1}{1+v^2} dv = \frac23 ( \arctan{v} |_1^{100}) \approx 0.5169 \dots$$

Some people I talked with got an answer above $10,000$ and my answer is not close at all! So I ask for your help, if you can review my work, I would be so thankful!
Thanks for helping!

Comment: Couldn't you have directly integrated over $y$ first knowing its limits in terms of $x$ and then integrated over x obtaining limits from circle.

Comment: @gemspark It is changing its sign (because it's a circle) one is $+ \sqrt{}$ and the second is $- \sqrt{}$ so it's more of an headache..

Comment: I think it does not matter here since $\frac{y}{x}$ is always positive. So signs of $x$ and $y$ are same all the time.

Comment: Your mistake is that you mixed up your $u$ bounds with your $v$ bounds when you actually started to take the integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In polar coordinates, the region $D$ is equivalent to $$D = \{(r, \theta) : (1 \le r \le 10) \cap (\tfrac{\pi}{6} \le \theta \le \tfrac{\pi}{3})\}.$$  The proof is straightforward after noting that $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$ and $\tan \theta = \frac{y}{x}$.  Consequently, the desired volume is easily expressed as an integral in cylindrical coordinates: $$V = \int_{r=1}^{10} \int_{\theta = \pi/6}^{\pi/3} r^3 \, d\theta \, dr.$$

Comment: How did you know that it would turn to $( \frac{ \pi}{6} \leq \theta \leq \frac{ \pi}{3} ) $ ? and why is it $r^3$ and not $r^2$ if $r^2 =x^2+y^2$ ?

Comment: @StackOMeow Because upon dividing by $x$, we obtain $$1/\sqrt{3} \le \tan \theta \le \sqrt{3}$$ when $x > 0$, and taking the inverse tangent yields $\pi/6 \le \theta \le \pi/3$.  When $x < 0$, we get an inequality that is never satisfied.

Comment: Is it a mistake that it's $r^3$ and not $r^2$ ? And does the order of integration flipped? because we first integrate $r^3$ over $dr$ no?

Comment: @StackOMeow Because the differential area element in cylindrical coordinates is $r \, dr \, d\theta$; i.e., the Jacobian of the transformation from Cartesian to polar is $r$.

Comment: @StackOMeow The order of integration is irrelevant because the integrand is a separable function of $r$ and $\theta$:  $$\int_{r=1}^{10} \int_{\theta=\pi/6}^{\pi/3} r^3 \, d\theta \, dr = \int_{r=1}^{10} r^3 \, dr \int_{\theta=\pi/6}^{\pi/3} 1 \, d\theta.$$

Comment: Thanks for the amazing approach! What about my approach? Why did it fail, are you noticing mistakes there? I am confused as in your approach I got $\frac{3333 \pi}{24}$

Comment: @heropup Can you explain more when you say we don't get any other range than the once you are integrating over? I mean isn't $\pi + \frac{\pi}{6} \lt \theta \lt \pi + \frac{\pi}{3}$ also a valid range?

Comment: @StackOMeow Your answer is too small by a factor of $3$.  Check your arithmetic.  As for your other question:  what happens if you choose $x = y = -1$?  Does that satisfy the original inequality?  So why would $\theta = 5\pi /4$, which is between $7\pi/6$ and $4\pi/3$, be included?  Hint:  when you divide an inequality by a negative number, the direction of the inequality reverses.

Comment: @heropup Can I directly calculate $$V = \int_{x=1}^{10} \int_{y = x/\sqrt{3}}^{\sqrt{3}x} x^2 + y^2 \, dxdy$$ ? Is it because inherently I haven't considered the circle property here? Can you suggest a way to incorporate that here ? Or help with the changes here so that direct integration over $x$ and $y$ can be performed?

Comment: @gemspark No.  Sketch the region of integration and you will immediately see that your proposed limits of integration are incorrect.  You would need to write $$\int_{x=1/2}^{\sqrt{3}/2} \int_{y=\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{x \sqrt{3}} z \, dy \, dx + \int_{x=\sqrt{3}/2}^5 \int_{y=x/\sqrt{3}}^{x \sqrt{3}} z \, dy \, dx + \int_{x=5}^{5 \sqrt{3}} \int_{y=x/\sqrt{3}}^{\sqrt{100-x^2}} z \, dy \, dx$$ where $z = x^2+y^2$ as stated in the question.